# Webpack 4, AngularJS - Как сделать динамический импорт путей файлов modules в $ocLazyLoadProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

Перевожу старый проект на Webpack 4.
Проект был написан на Angular 1.5.*.

Есть следующая конструкция:

```js
export var modulesBoot = [{
  name: 'app',
    files: [
      'services/underscore.mixin',
    ],
    serie: true,
    cache: true
}]

$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
    asyncLoader: $script,
    events: true,
    modules: modulesBoot
});
```

Проблема заключается в том, что файлы после сборки динамически изменяют имена (с chunk). 
Как корректно можно передать динамически имена?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all"
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Это и так сделано